# Flask Passenger WSGI on Dreamhost

Tags: python, flask, passenger, dreamhost

First I followed the instructions in the tutorial on Matt Carrier's blog (although that assumed I would be making a subdirectory on my domain, when I'm not). Then I erased everything and started over with the instructions on the Dreamhost wiki page about Flask. Each time, I get a message in the browser reading: "An error occurred importing your passenger_wsgi.py". The [answer for this topic on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10386520/cant-get-flask-running-using-passenger-wsgi-on-dreamhost-shared-hosting/10389257) did not work for me.

My passenger_wsgi.py file is:

```
import sys, os
INTERP = os.path.join(os.environ['HOME'], 'flask_env', 'bin', 'python')
if sys.executable != INTERP:
    os.execl(INTERP, INTERP, *sys.argv)
sys.path.append(os.getcwd())

from flask import Flask
application = Flask(__name__)

sys.path.append('penguicon-trax')
from penguicon-trax.penguicontrax import app as application
```

penguicon-trax is the name of the directory Git creates when I clone my app into the virtualenv where I installed Flask (not in the public dir). The app is penguicontrax.py without the dash.

I made sure the indent on the fourth line of passenger_wsgi.py was a tab, not spaces.

I used the DreamHost webpanel (where I'm fully hosted) to make /home/username/flask_env/public and I marked the "Passenger (Ruby/Python apps only)" checkbox and clicked the "Change Settings" button.

I FTP'ed passenger_wsgi.py directly into my flask_env directory on Dreamhost. When I SSH into Dreamhost, ls on the command line gives me:

```
bin  lib            passenger_wsgi.pyc  public
include  passenger_wsgi.py  penguicon-trax
```

When I run passenger_wsgi.py through SSH, it gives me:

```
File "passenger_wsgi.py", line 11
  from penguicon-trax.penguicontrax import app as application
                ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

It also does this when I just use "from penguicon-trax import app as application".

When I change that line to remove the dash: "penguicontrax.penguicontrax" and run it, it gives me "ImportError: No module named penguicontrax".

If I change the line to "from penguicontrax import app as application" and run it through SSH, it gives me no error message or other output. However, my domain now gives a 404.

Can you tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

If your passenger_wsgi.py has the following code at the end of it:

```
from foo.bar import app as application
```

... then you need a sub-directory named "foo" with two files in it: one file named `bar.py` and another file named `__init__.py` so that Python recognizes that the directory contains module code.

In your example, remove the dash from the folder name (penguicon-trax), since [modules should have short, all-lowercase names](https://stackoverflow.com/a/761531). Then, your [Flask application code](http://flask.pocoo.org/) would be in a file in **$HOME/flask_env/penguicontrax/penguicontrax.py**  Lastly, run the following to try it out:

```
touch $HOME/flask_env/penguicontrax/__init__.py
python $HOME/flask_env/passenger_wsgi.py
```